# 新規登録したAWSの機能が使えません。

Tags: aws

新規登録したAWSの機能が使えません。

下記の画像のように `You are not subscribed to this service. Please go to http://aws.amazon.com to subscribe` エラーが出てしまって、AWS機能が使えません。
決済の問題でしょうか？
どう問い合わせれば治るでしょうか？

[image]

Comment: サポートに問い合わせるべきでは…？

Comment: 質問に貼られたメッセージによると、料金を抑えるために、"30分後に自動休止する"設定になっているようです。
エラーが起きたのは、AWSでLinuxインスタンスを起動してから３０分以上経過してからという事はないですか？（Linuxが休止されているので、AWS上のLINUXが使えなかったという状況が想像されるのですが）

Answer (score 0):

ひとまず、このエラーメッセージと関連する AWS ナレッジセンターの記事はこちらのようです。2020 年 3 月現在、アカウントのステータスを更新することを勧めています。

- [AWS マネジメントコンソールでサービスにアクセスする際の問題を解決するにはどうすればよいですか?](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-access-service/)

いくつかの AWS Developer Forums ではクレジットカード等決済手段の認証を確認せよと書いているものもありましたので、こちらも合わせて確認するのが良さそうです。